# Flutter maps add a marker 10 kilometers north of my location

Tags: flutter, maps

Looking to add a marker on a flutter map 10 kilometers from my current location.

I cant for the life of me figure this out!

I can draw circles at 10k intervals, I can measure between two known points.

Just cant seem to figure out how to add a marker 10k away say to the north of me?

any help would be great, this must be a common scenario.

Comment: Found the solution https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map_math